# 'i' does not name a type

Tags: c++, arrays, function

This is the question I Had

> ABC Company is one of the leading beverage distribution companies  in USA. They are 
>   currently  distributing  three  beverages  namely  Fanta,  Coca  Cola  and  Sprite  via  their  island 
>   wide sales team which consists  of  100 salesmen.  Apart from the basic salary,  salesmen  will 
>   be given a  commission  based on  their  sales.  Write a  complete  C++ program  to automate the 
>   following functionalities.
>    Define  suitable  arrays  to  store  basic  salary,  sales  of  each  beverage,  total  sales, 
>   commission, and gross salary of each salesman.
>
> Write (a) function(s) to input basic salaries, and sales of each
>   beverage of each salesman.
>
> Write a function to calculate the total sales of each salesman.
>
> Write  a  function  to  calculate  the  commission  of  each 
>   salesman.  The  commission  (per  bottle) is given based on their
>   sales as follows.
>
> **0 < Sales <= 25000    – $ 0.00**
>
> **25000 < Sales <= 50000    – $ 0.25**
>
> **50000 < Sales    – $ 0.50**
>
> Write a function to calculate the gross salary of each salesman.
>
> Write a function to print total sales, commission, and the gross
>   salary of each salesman.
>
> Call the above functions  accordingly  within the main function  to 
>   prepare  (input, process,  output) salary details of all the salesmen.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int MyVar=100;


for (int i=0;i<MyVar;i++)
{
    int InputSalesandSalary(int BasicSalary[],CocaColaSales[],FantaSales[],SpriteSales[])
    {
        int BasicSalary[i];
        int CocaColaSales[i];
        int FantaSales[i];
        int SpriteSales[i];

        cout<<"Enter Basic Salary : ";
        cin>>BasicSalary[i];
        cout<<"Enter Coca Cola Sales : ";
        cin>>CocaColaSales[i];
        cout<<"Enter Fanta Sales : ";
        cin>>FantaSales[i];
        cout<<"Enter Sprite Sales : ";
        cin>>SpriteSales[i];
    }
}

int CalcTotalSales(int CocaColaSales[],int FantaSales[],int SpriteSales[])
{
    for (int j=0;j<MyVar;j++)
    {
        int TotalSales[j]=CocaColaSales[j]+FantaSales[j]+SpriteSales[j];
    }
}

int CalcCommision(int TotalSales[])
{
    for (int k=0;k<MyVar;k++)
    {
        if (int TotalSales[k]<=25000)

            double Commision[k]=0;

        else if (TotalSales[k]<=5000)

            double Commision[k]=0.25*TotalSales[k];

        else
            double Commision[k]=0.50*TotalSales[k];

    }
}

int CalcGrossSalary(int BasicSalary[],double Commision[])
{
    for (int l=0;l<MyVar;l++)
    {
        double GrossSalary[l]=BasicSalary[l]+Commision[k]
    }
}

int main()
{
    int BasicSalary[MyVar];
    int CocaColaSales[MyVar];
    int FantaSales[MyVar];
    int SpriteSales[MyVar;
    int TotalSales[MyVar];
    int Commision[MyVar];
    int GrossSalary[MyVar];

    int InputSalesandSalary(BasicSalary,CocaColaSales,FantaSales,SpriteSales);
    int CalcTotalSales(CocaColaSales,FantaSales,SpriteSales);
    int CalcCommision(TotalSales);
    int CalcGrossSalary(BasicSalary,Commision);

    for (int m=0;m<MyVar;m++)
    {
        cout<<"Total Sales : "<<TotalSales;
        cout<<"\n Commision : "<<Commision;
        cout<<"\n GrossSalary : " <<GrossSalary;
    }
}
```

Then I have coded this,Unfortunately I'm Having many errors.

```
|7|error: 'i' does not name a type|
|7|error: 'i' does not name a type|
||In function 'int CalcTotalSales(int*, int*, int*)':|
|31|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'TotalSales' [-Wvla]|
|31|error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer|
|31|warning: unused variable 'TotalSales' [-Wunused-variable]|
|33|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
||In function 'int CalcCommision(int*)':|
|39|error: expected primary-expression before 'int'|
|39|error: expected ')' before 'int'|
|41|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'Commision' [-Wvla]|
|41|error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer|
|41|warning: unused variable 'Commision' [-Wunused-variable]|
|45|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'Commision' [-Wvla]|
|45|error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer|
|45|warning: unused variable 'Commision' [-Wunused-variable]|
|48|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'Commision' [-Wvla]|
|48|error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer|
|48|warning: unused variable 'Commision' [-Wunused-variable]|
|51|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
||In function 'int CalcGrossSalary(int*, double*)':|
|57|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'GrossSalary' [-Wvla]|
|57|error: 'k' was not declared in this scope|
|58|error: expected ',' or ';' before '}' token|
|57|warning: unused variable 'GrossSalary' [-Wunused-variable]|
|59|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
||In function 'int main()':|
|63|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'BasicSalary' [-Wvla]|
|64|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'CocaColaSales' [-Wvla]|
|65|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'FantaSales' [-Wvla]|
|66|error: expected ']' before ';' token|
|67|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'TotalSales' [-Wvla]|
|68|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'Commision' [-Wvla]|
|69|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'GrossSalary' [-Wvla]|
|71|error: 'SpriteSales' was not declared in this scope|
|71|error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]|
|71|warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]|
|71|warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]|
|72|error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]|
|72|warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]|
|73|error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
|74|error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]|
|74|warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]|
|74|error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
|71|warning: unused variable 'InputSalesandSalary' [-Wunused-variable]|
|72|warning: unused variable 'CalcTotalSales' [-Wunused-variable]|
|73|warning: unused variable 'CalcCommision' [-Wunused-variable]|
|74|warning: unused variable 'CalcGrossSalary' [-Wunused-variable]|
```

I'm a beginner to C++

Comment: You have a loop at file scope. And a function inside its block.

Comment: And so your question is...?

Comment: my question is what is wrong with code???

Comment: @CplusCoder, StoryTeller already answered that question.

Comment: Those errors are pretty self explanatory. To elaborate on them would take a [whole book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Why are you declaring a method in a for-loop. That's probably what's wrong and you're losing reference to the 'i'. But you should go back to basics with C++ and stack overflow isn't a place for beginners to ask 'what's wrong with my code?'

Comment: @Rambatino unless they have a fire resistant coat - because they're going to get flamed  (rightly or wrongly is another story)

Answer (score -1):

Without You genius help , I was lucky to code better :-P .

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int MyVar=100;

void InputSalesandSalary(int BasicSalary[],int CocaColaSales[],int FantaSales[],int SpriteSales[]){
for (int i=0;i<MyVar;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Salesman No  "<<i+1<<" : ";
        cout<<"\n____________________________";
        cout<<"\n\nEnter Basic Salary : ";
        cin>>BasicSalary[i];
        cout<<"Enter Coca Cola Sales : ";
        cin>>CocaColaSales[i];
        cout<<"Enter Fanta Sales : ";
        cin>>FantaSales[i];
        cout<<"Enter Sprite Sales : ";
        cin>>SpriteSales[i];
        cout<<"\n____________________________\n";
    }
}

void CalcTotalSales(int CocaColaSales[],int FantaSales[],int SpriteSales[], int TotalSales[])
   {
       for (int j=0;j<MyVar;j++)
        {
            TotalSales[j]={CocaColaSales[j]+FantaSales[j]+SpriteSales[j]};
        }

   }

void CalcCommision(int TotalSales[],double Commision[])
{
    for (int k=0;k<MyVar;k++)
    {
        if (TotalSales[k]<=25000)
            Commision[k]=0;

        else if (TotalSales[k]<=50000)

            Commision[k]=0.25*TotalSales[k];

        else
            Commision[k]=0.50*TotalSales[k];

    }
}

int CalcGrossSalary(int BasicSalary[],double Commision[],double GrossSalary[])
{
    for (int l=0;l<MyVar;l++)
    {
        GrossSalary[l]=BasicSalary[l]+Commision[l];
        GrossSalary;
    }
}

int outputSalary(int TotalSales[],double Commision[],double GrossSalary[])
{
    for(int m=0;m<MyVar;m++)
    {
        cout<<"______________________"<<endl;
        cout<<"Sales No  "<<m+1<<" : "<<endl;
        cout<<"Total Sales : "<<TotalSales[m]<<endl;
        cout<<"Commision : "<<Commision[m]<<endl;
        cout<<"GrossSalary : " <<GrossSalary[m]<<endl;
        cout<<"______________________"<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
   int BasicSalary[MyVar];
    int CocaColaSales[MyVar];
    int FantaSales[MyVar];
    int SpriteSales[MyVar];
    int TotalSales[MyVar];
    double Commision[MyVar];
    double GrossSalary[MyVar];


    InputSalesandSalary(BasicSalary,CocaColaSales,FantaSales,SpriteSales);
    CalcTotalSales(CocaColaSales,FantaSales,SpriteSales,TotalSales);
    CalcCommision(TotalSales,Commision);
    CalcGrossSalary(BasicSalary,Commision,GrossSalary);
    outputSalary(TotalSales,Commision,GrossSalary);
}
```

Comment: I think you miss-understand how to use stack overflow

Comment: Think so.Thank You !